# Flutter how I will get Future<List<Placemark>> to <List<Placemark>?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a provider where a method , by this method if I send lat and long it will give me place name.

```
Future<List<Placemark>> getAndSetAddressFromLatLong(double startLat)async {
        List<Placemark> placemarksStart = await placemarkFromCoordinates(startLat,startLong);
        return placemarksStart;
}
```

So, When I'm trying to call and fetch the data in view file like below

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

var data = Provider.of<MapProvider>(context).getAndSetAddressFromLatLong(
    widget.history.startLat!.toDouble(), 
    widget.history.startLong!.toDouble(),
).then((value) => value);

print(data);
```

I'm getting the output `I/flutter (25255): Instance of 'Future<List<Placemark>>'` , But In then() if I print value without return I'm getting my desire list.

How I will get `List<Placemark>` here from Instance of 'Future<List>' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using provider call `notifyListeners()` after awaiting the results. In the widget use consumer to show the results

```
List<Placemark> _placemarksStart = [];
List<Placemark> get placemarksStart => [..._placemarksStart];

Future<void> getAndSetAddressFromLatLong(double startLat, double startLong) async {
    _placemarksStart = await placemarkFromCoordinates(startLat,startLong);
    notifyListeners();
}
```

Widget, similarly you can achieve loading with a boolean

```
Consumer<MyType>(
  builder: (context, provider, child) {
    if (provider.placemarksStart.isEmpty) {
      return Center(child: Text('Loading...'),);
    }
    return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final item = provider.placemarksStart[index];
      return Text("TODO");
    }, itemCount: provider.placemarksStart.length,);
  },
),
```

And call the method `getAndSetAddressFromLatLong` in the `initState`

Comment: Then how can I solve this problem ? BY Future  builded ?

Answer (score 0):

```
late List<placemark> data;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

Provider.of<MapProvider>(context).getAndSetAddressFromLatLong(
    widget.history.startLat!.toDouble(), 
    widget.history.startLong!.toDouble(),
).then((value){
  data = value;
  print(data);
}
);
```